# woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect not firing facebook AddToCart event

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, facebook-pixel

I use the following code in functions.php to redirect my Woocommerce customers to the checkout page when they add a product to the cart:

```
function redirect_checkout_add_cart( $url ) {
    $url = get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' ) ); 
    return $url;
}  
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect','redirect_checkout_add_cart');
```

The problem is that the facebook add to cart event is not fired by this redirect method. How can I redirect the customer to the checkout page and fire the add to cart facebook pixel event?